# Сравнивание двух объектов

Tags: java

Имеется абсолютно рабочий класс с методом в котором сравниваются два объекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Непонятна только одна запись. Зачем при сравнении вызывать у свойства `ob` свойство `num` ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А не сразу взять и указать свойство `ob` для сравнения с `num` ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако нельзя :( Вопрос, Почему?

Comment: Здесь сравниваются не два объекта а свойства этих объектов num, которые наследуются от Number

Comment: Разве в Java решена проблема подобного сравнения чисел с плавающей запятой? Мне кажется, что Вы в любом случае делаете что-то не то)

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код в виде текста

Comment: потому что у класса `NumericFns` нет метода `doubleValue`

Answer (score 2):

ob - это класс, а вы сравниваете числовые значения, переменную num. Вот если бы ob был классом унаследованным от Number, вот тогда бы прокатило такое

Comment: Ну исходя из этой записи class NumericFns<T extends Number> следует, что ob тоже будет типа Number
Ну или по крайней мере мы ждем объект такого типа Number, которому доступны метод doubleEqual

Comment: Ну от List<String> вы ведь не ожидаете объекта String, в итоге это ведь объект List

Comment: Не ob будет типа Number, а T.

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что для подобного функционала не использована реализация интерфейса `Comparabe` и переопределение метода `compareTo()`, однако, весь код логичен. Логика проста, во время сравнения этих двух объектов сравнивается текущий объект, тот что слева от знака равенства и второй объект, которой передается в качестве параметра в функцию. У текущего объедка мы сразу получаем поле `num`, но вот чтобы получить поле `num` у переданного объекта, нам необходимо обратиться к нему именно вот так: `ob.num`, отсюда и такая конструкция

Comment: Спасибо за детальный ответ, теперь дошло :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы сравниваете не сами объекты,а поля объектов.
2. Так вы double правильно не сравните.
   Посмотрите пример кода сравнения для прояснения ситуации:

   package underwaterRocks.myDouble;

   ```
   public class MyDouble {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           double dx = 1.4 - 0.1 - 0.1 - 0.1 - 0.1;
           System.out.println("dx = " + dx); // dx = 0.9999999999999997
           System.out.print("Сравнение (dx == 1.0):");
           System.out.println(dx == 1.0); // false, потому что 1.0 не равно 0.9999999999999997

           /*как правильно сравнивать double*/
           final double EPSILON = 1E-14;
           double xx = 1.4 - 0.1 - 0.1 - 0.1 - 0.1;
           double xy = 1.0;
           /* сравниваем xx c xy */
           if (Math.abs(xx - xy) < EPSILON) {
               System.out.println(xx + " это примерно равно " + xy + " EPSILON = " + EPSILON);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Чтобы сравнить объекты вам нужно сравнить все их поля и hashcode. Тогда они будут эквивалентны. Или сравнить все их поля, тогда они будут не эквивалентны, а равны.

Comment: EPSILON - не панацея. Его невозможно подобрать для всех случаев. Ведь иногда нужно сравнивать числа разных порядков, например, с таким epsilon все числа <1e-14 равны. Иногда применяют относительный epsilon, скажем `xx/1e6`